# Input handling to create a sudoku grid

Tags: prolog, dcg

I have programmed many things in many programming languages, and Prolog is not one of those languages. I am supposed to write a program that will solve a sudoku puzzle when given a puzzle representation as input.

My idea:
Store all supplied numbers in a list of lists (list of rows), and brute force the possible options until one fits (I know, it's not the most elegant, but I don't have a lot of time to spend writing out the logic to solve the puzzle conventionally). But, being new to Prolog, I am having some difficulty understanding the way of going about things. The input is given in a text file in the form of rows looking like

```
1-2---34-
-34--1-5-
```

and so on and so forth. My code to read and print the file is:

```
readPuzzle(File) :-
  see(File),
  repeat,
  get_char(X),
  (X = end_of_file, !
   ;
   write(X),
   fail
  ),
  seen.
```

This works all well and good. So let's say I try to build this list by adding a `W = []`
just above `see(File)` and replace `write(X)` with `W = [W|X]`. From my experience, this should create a long list of all of the chars supplied from the text file.
It doesn't.
Someone please either

- tell me a better more prological way of accomplishing the task ahead of me
- explain how I can work around this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several ways of accomplish the specification reading. If you are willing to reuse your code, I would suggest to use assertz:

```
:- dynamic onechar/1.

readPuzzle(File) :-
  see(File),
  repeat,
  get_char(X),
  (X = end_of_file, !
   ;
   asssertz(onechar(X)), % write(X),
   fail
  ),
  seen.
```

and use

```
 ...,  findall(L, retract(onechar(C)), Cs), ...
```

to get the list of chars read, then you will need to split the list in lines, discarding lines' separators.

Otherwise, instead of asserting/retracting, we can use service predicate that collects more structured input, and constraints length while reading:

```
readPuzzle(File, Puzzle) :-
  see(File),
  length(Puzzle, 9),  % this allocates a list of unbound variables
  maplist(read_a_line, Puzzle),
  seen.

read_a_line(Line) :-
  length(Line, 9),
  maplist(get_char, Line),
  get_char(_). % get rid of nl
```

For an example of how this works in SWI-Prolog:

```
?- length(L,9),see(user),maplist(get,L),seen.
|: 987654321

L = [57, 56, 55, 54, 53, 52, 51, 50, 49].
```

**update**

Here is another way, using *accumulators* to collect structured input and size..

```
readPuzzle(File, Puzzle, Length) :-
  see(File),
  readLines([], 0, Puzzle, Length),
  seen.

readLines(SoFar, CountSoFar, Lines, CountLines) :-
  get_char(C), % lookahead
  C \= end_of_file,
  readLine(C, [], Line),
  M is SoFar + 1,
  readLines([Line|SoFar], M, Lines, CountLines).
readLines(Lines, TotLines, Lines, TotLines).

readLine(C, Line, Line) :-
 C == 10.
readLine(C, SoFar, Line) :-
 get_char(S),
 readLine(S, [C|SoFar], Line).
```

Comment: This helps a TON. Thank you. Now say, I didn't know what size this sudoku puzzle is. How would you keep track of how many characters are read before say a '\n' is hit? Just do something like what you've given here and provide a ! when '\n' is hit and then get the length..?

Comment: Ahhh thank you so much! You have no idea how much this helps. Prolog is very foreign to me..

Answer (score 2):

I would write a DCG that describes the puzzle syntax, and then use library(pio) to use the DCG to read puzzles from files. For example:

```
:- use_module(library(pio)).

puzzle([Line|Lines]) -->
        line(Line),
        !,
        puzzle(Lines).
puzzle([]) --> [].

line([]) --> "\n".
line([_|Ls]) --> "-", !, line(Ls).
line([N|Ls]) --> [D], { name(N, [D]) }, line(Ls).
```

When I save your example puzzle in the file "sud.txt", I get:

```
?- phrase_from_file(puzzle(Ps), 'sud.txt'), maplist(writeln, Ps).
[1,_G517,2,_G526,_G529,_G532,3,4,_G547]
[_G553,3,4,_G568,_G571,1,_G580,5,_G589]
Ps = [[1, _G517, 2, _G526, _G529, _G532, 3, 4|...], [_G553, 3, 4, _G568, _G571, 1, _G580|...]].
```